# Preposition after guideline

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct?

> I wrote a guideline **of** 5 questions

or

> I wrote a guideline **with** 5 questions

or something else?

It is just about the prepositon. Nevermind that questions doesn't fit to guideline.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Either one can work. I'd interpret the first as having a word elided or implied:

> I wrote a guideline [consisting] of 5 questions

while the other uses *with* as meaning "to have" – in other words, for the purpose of saying what [possessions, qualities, or features someone or something has](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/with):

- a girl with red hair
- a room with a high ceiling

In this case, that "something" is the guideline you wrote:

- a guideline with five questions

Answer (score 0):

If you give a rule, instruction, or information on how to solve the five questions, you usually use the preposition 'on' or 'for' after the noun guideline, though the use of the preposition of/with is also possible grammatically.

I wrote a guideline on/for 5 questions.